How exactly did the Thai script tone marking system evolve?
The Wikipedia page "Thai script" gives a helpful summary table of tones to tone diacritics that looks completely absurd at first glance; I've been trying to figure it out but haven't found much on the Internet.
I have a good grasp of how tonogenesis occurred and why each consonant ended up in the high, mid or low class, but I just can't figure out how that would result in the current system where often the resulting tones are the exact opposite of what you would expect judging by consonant class and syllable type.
I've read Morén and Zsiga 2006 so I understand the details of how the tones are realized and specified in modern Thai, and I am aware of the reconstructed 3/4 tone system of the proto-language.
Where can I find a resource that explains how the orthographical tone system in Thai evolved?

There have been some investigations into this over the years, most notably from:

Diller, Antony (2017) Early Thai orthography: Innovative tone-marking or recent hoax?
Diller, Antony (1996) Thai Orthography and the History of Marking Tone
Hartmann, John F (1980) A Model for the Alignment of Dialects in Southwestern Tai
Pittayawat Pittayaporn (2016) Chindamani and reconstruction of Thai tones in the 17th century

Tone markers 1 and 2
On Sukhothai Inscription No. 1 จารึกหลักที่ 1, there is the consistent use of two tone marks, a vertical line above, and a plus sign above, both of which can be seen from the very first two lines of the inscription.
For example, the word transcribed <chɯː> from the first line is cognate with modern Standard Central Thai ชื่อ and Lao ຊື່.
The first word, transcribed <pɔː>, is cognate with modern Standard Central Thai พ่อ and Lao ພໍ່. Similarly, the other remaining lexeme with a tone 1 marker, <mæː>, is cognate with Standard Central Thai แม่ and Lao ແມ່.
Tone 1 markers are thus consistent across all three scripts, and broadly across the cognates that would be expected from Modern Central Thai and Lao.
This can also be seen for the three lexemes in the second line that have Tone 2 markers: <nɔːŋ> (น้อง / ນ້ອງ), <thɔːŋ> (ท้อง / ທ້ອງ), <haː> (ห้า / ຫ້າ).
These two tone markers are all the tone markers found in the Sukhothai script, and correspond cleanly with what comparative linguistics now calls tone B and tone C of Proto-Tai respectively (with tone A left as the unmarked tone, and tone D distinguishable by its final obstruent consonant). As Diller (1996) states:

It is important to emphasise that for the hundred or so items of Proto-Tai provenance on the inscription, tone marks accord with Proto-Tai tones as reconstructed through comparative evidence with virtually no exceptions.

This forms the basis for the following claim:

The Sukhothai script has a good claim to be the first case of systematic tone marking in any language.

However, from other Sukhothai inscriptions, it is possible to see that the innovation of tone marking was not adopted wholesale, with some inscriptions having none, and others using it only with words that need disambiguating. The plus-shaped tone 2 marker also changes towards its current form in Thai and Lao.

Tone splits
In the Ayutthaya period, we see a reduction in tone marking. The tone 1 marker is also seen in a re-purposed form, the ฝนทอง marker, basically marking where an inherent vowel should be pronounced (either in polysyllabic words, or at the end of the word) rather than silenced. There are other vowel-type uses documented.
Having said that, scribes in the late Ayutthaya were documented as understanding the tone marks. However, the difference in the tonal system of the language was evident. It is believed that initial devoicing was affecting the Thai language throughout this period, bringing about a huge tone split and re-merger:

Early Thai developed a grossly over-complex tone system which was subsequently drastically
reduced. [The] dialectal variation essentially reflects alternative simplifications.

By the 17th century, when French merchant La Loubère visits Siam, he notes (with a translation into 17th century English) how the consonants affect the "accent":

Ils ont beaucoup d’accent comme les Chinois : ils chantent presque en parlant ; & l’Alphabeth Siamois commence par six caractéres différens, qui ne valent tous qu’un K. plus ou moins fort, & diversement accentué. Car quoy que dans la prononciation les accents soient naturellement sur les voyéles, ils en marquent néanmoins quelques-uns en variant les consonnes, qui d’ailleurs font d’une même valeur.
They have a great deal of Accent, like the Chineses: they do almost sing in speaking: and the Siamese Alphabet begins with six different Characters, which do all countervail only a K, more or less strong, and variously accented. For though in the pronunciation the Accents be naturally upon Vowels, yet they do mark some by varying the Consonants, which otherwise are of the same weight.

He also only documents two "accent" marks, although he concentrates on the vowel usage, not on the use as a tone marker.
EDIT: How the specific classes emerged is subject to much more speculation, as phonetic descriptions of tone are harder to come by. Most work in this area has been done synchronically, such as Hartmann (1980).
From diachronic evidence, it is perhaps easier to conceptualise the high/mid/low consonants as intersecting with proto-Tai and Sukhothai tone A/B/C, producing 9-category tone system for "smooth" syllables. Tone D, with its final consonant, then intersects with vowel length as well as initial consonants (so-called Gedney's Tone Box). These are then simplified down in different ways, as Hartmann explains:

The dialects of Upper and Middle Southwestern Tai have split along the clearest lines. There seems to be little doubt about the unity of these two subgroups if examined from the standpoint of tonal splits. However, when we are pressed to demonstrate the unity of the Lower Southwestern group or Lao-Siamese-Southern Thai, the patterns of tonal development are not all that transparent.

In the case of Central Thai (the basis for both Standard Thai):

When we move into the Central Thai or Siamese region and look at the Bangkok tonal
array, tripartition is not as immediately apparent. However, if we put the Bangkok array alongside the not-too-distant and mutually intelligible dialects of Khorat, Roi-Et and Ubon, a pattern of a three-way split followed by idiosyncratic arrangements for coalescence in each dialect emerges.


Tone markers 3 and 4
It is in the 18th century that tone 3 and 4 markers were introduced, and these were incorporated into the standard orthography that was set in the mid-19th century. Apparently, these specific tone markers were...

originally to accommodate the names of Chinese immigrants and junk captains.

Hence Thai words tone 3 and tone 4 are generally from Hokkien and Teochew forms of Southern Min Chinese (with many of them being indistinguishable between the two families). However, there are some Cantonese-derived forms there too.
The correspondence between tones in the various subdialects of Hokkien, Teochew, Hainanese, Hakka and Cantonese is difficult to determine, and there must have been significant dialect levelling amongst the Teochew-dominated Thai Chinese. The way tone sandhi works in Hokkien, Teochew and Hainanese complicates tracing the correspondences.
However, given how the tone splits occurred, Central Thai allocated syllables with voiceless unaspirated and [newly] voiced obstruent initial consonants to mid tones, with tone marker 1 exhibiting low tone and tone marker 2 exhibiting falling tone; none were in the rising or high tones.
In loanwords from the Chinese varieties, voiceless unaspirated b-, g-, t- and voiced b/bh- frequently had 'high' tones (e.g. 馬 /be⁵³~⁵²/ in Xiamen and Chaoshan, becoming เบ๊) and rising tones (e.g. 粿條 /ke⁴²⁻²⁴ tiau²⁴/, with apparently Singaporean Hokkien tones, becoming ก๋วยเตี๋ยว), necessitating the creation of these tone markers.
Note where modern Hokkien and Teochew varieties use high falling tone, one that might seem closer to modern Central Thai falling tone (which would be tone marker 2), these actually got tone marker 3, giving it the high tone. I have not been able to determine this is a tone shift in Hokkien or Teochew in the last 200 years, or whether this is a shift that happened in Thai.
Note also that tonal "holes" in the scheme for aspirated obstruents were very easy: the use of relevant low or high class of consonant and the correct length of syllable was all that was required (given that syllable length was not contrastive in Hokkien or Teochew). The first two tone markers were sufficient.
The case of sonorants (written exclusively with low-class consonants) in the rising and low tones was also common. That used a longstanding workaround, of ห prefixing the consonant to 'turn' it into a high-class consonant. See, for example, Thai บะหมี่ for Hokkien or Teochew 肉麵 bah-mī (/ba(ʔ)³²⁻⁵³ mĩ²²/), where the low tone of the final syllable in the source was preserved using หม as a high-class sonorant with tone marker 1.

Thank you for the answer, but maybe I didn't phrase my question clearly enough because I was rather looking for the specifics of both how the 3~5 proto-tones and 3~4 onset categories evolved into the strange current system (where for instance low class + constriction = high tone or high class + constriction = low tone, etc...) AND, on top of that, how specifically the markers were diachronically assigned to these evolving tones.

@trerri Appreciated. The change in the system you refer to is an Ayutthaya period change, through the 16th and 17th centuries, and is indeed very confusing (as tonogenesis often is).
